# Tween functions for series of menus wont work after the 1st

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having a problem with a series of drop down menus i'm trying to make. I have 3 buttons, each of which when hovered over, drops down a sub menu with options. The problem I'm running into is that the first menu works, it drops down as it should. The second and third menus however do not work, and I don't understand why. I'm not getting an error code, and some googling directed me to people who were having similar problems suggesting flash garbage collection might be what is causing my issue. i'm not sure how to structure it so that this wont happen. I should also add that this is my first time posting so I apologize for any format issues in the post, and I'm very new to coding so any help will be much appreciated, I don't really know the  questions to ask to get me going in the right direction.

Thankyou for your time

The code I have so far is as follows

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.Regular;

stop();

menu_cont.paint_rect.alpha = 0;
menu_cont.trim_rect.alpha = 0;
menu_cont.wheels_rect.alpha = 0;

menu_cont.paint_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, paintRollOver);
menu_cont.paint_rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, paintMouseOut);
menu_cont.trim_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, trimRollOver);
menu_cont.trim_rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, trimMouseOut);
menu_cont.wheels_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, wheelsRollOver);
menu_cont.wheels_rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, wheelsMouseOut);

var paintMenuTween:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.paint_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.paint_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
var paintMenuTween2:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.paint_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.paint_menu.y, -15, .5, true);
var trimMenuTween:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.trim_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.trim_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
var trimMenuTween2:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.trim_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.trim_menu.y, -15, .5, true);
var wheelsMenuTween:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.wheels_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.wheels_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
var wheelsMenuTween2:Tween = new Tween (menu_cont.wheels_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.wheels_menu.y, -15, .5, true);

function paintRollOver (event:MouseEvent):void {
    paintMenuTween = new Tween (menu_cont.paint_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.paint_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
    trace ("paint over")
}

function paintMouseOut (event:MouseEvent):void {
    paintMenuTween2 = new Tween (menu_cont.paint_menu, "y", 
Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.paint_menu.y, -15, .5, true);
trace ("paint out")
}

function trimRollOver (event:MouseEvent):void {
    trimMenuTween = new Tween (menu_cont.trim_menu, "y", Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.trim_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
    trace("trim over")
}

function trimMouseOut (event:MouseEvent):void {
    trimMenuTween2 = new Tween (menu_cont.trim_menu, "y", Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.trim_menu.y, -15, .5, true);
    trace("trim out")
}

function wheelsRollOver (event:MouseEvent):void {
    wheelsMenuTween = new Tween (menu_cont.wheels_menu, "y", Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.wheels_menu.y, 50, .5, true);
    trace ("wheels over")
}

function wheelsMouseOut (event:MouseEvent):void {
    wheelsMenuTween2 = new Tween (menu_cont.wheels_menu, "y", Regular.easeOut,menu_cont.wheels_menu.y, -15, .5, true);
    trace ("wheels out")
}
```

Comment: There's nothing visually wrong with your code (beside the very fact of duplicated code which is algorithmically wrong). I advise to put trace(...) into the handlers to learn if the targets you addressing with Tweens actually exist and not null and does not have empty duplicates, check the instance names in your designs, etc.

Comment: Double check that you have correct z-order for all of those elements; _rect objects behind _btn objects I assume.

Comment: You don't have to declare all the tweens in the beginning if you are creating new tweens on rollover and rollout. You are settings all menus to invisible (alpha = 0) in the beginning. Where do you set them to visible again ? Maybe that's the problem. Do you see your rollover traces for the other menus?

Comment: @ Organis, Thankyou for pointing out the duplicate code, the traces also helped to identify that the tweens do exist and are working.

Comment: @ Organis The problem was instance names, and specifically the second and third menus not being directed to the correct masks, such that they were always masked as invisible. The events were happening, I just couldnt see them. @ Kaarto, the z- order was not the issue although thankyou for pointing it out as a possibility. @ Philarmon, the alpha to zero is for the mouse out even shapes so they always remain at zero. Thankyou for the advice